# Connect to SQL server 2014 management studio with PHP

Tags: php, asp.net, sql-server, database

Is there a way to connect to Microsoft's SQL server 2014 management studio with PHP?

I was able to connect to the same database with ASP.NET, but I'm not seeing anything online on how to connect to that type of database with PHP.  All I'm seeing is Mysql, not SQL server 2014 management studio with PHP.

this is what I have so far to connect via PHP

```
<?php>
$myServer = "LALA";
$myDB = "LGWeb";

// connection to database
$dbhandle = msql_connect($myServer)
    or die("couldn't connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
// select database to work with
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB,$dbhandle)
    or die("couldn't connect to database - $myDB");
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])){
    include('')





}// end of main if

?>
```

I changed my database names and server name in code above.  But that's the basic idea.  Just trying to connect to it with PHP.

This is how I connected to it with ASP.NET

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LALAConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=LALA;Initial Catalog=LGWeb;Integrated Security=True"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />


  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php

Comment: don't need username and password ?

Comment: @nanis No it doesn't need a username or password.